# Iterating through fields?

Tags: c#, variables, loops

First of all, I'm not entirely sure how to phrase this or what to search for if someone asked before.

Say I have multiple labels: label1, label2, label3, label4, etc...

Now, **I know this works in PHP so I'm wondering if there is a way to do this in C#** - 
Can I somehow iterate through these labels to set their values in a loop?

i.e.

```
string[] something = new string[3] { "text", "text", "text" };

for (int i = 0; i < something.length; i++)
{
    labels(i).Text = something[i];
}
```

Comment: what are there labels ? ASP.NET label control ?

Comment: First, it's called a `label`. Second, why not make an array of these labels? Lastly, if this is Winforms, you can use `Controls.Find("labelName")`.

Comment: Yes, believe it or not C# does support `for` loops - why don't you just try it and see before asking a question?

Comment: @James That wasn't the question. Read again. To all others, thanks for your help!

Comment: I read your question just fine, my point still stands if you actually just tried it out before asking a question you would have probably found your answer. Also, your question lacked sufficient information, all answers below were at best guesses based on the fact you mentioned "*label*" but no context (ASP.NET, WPF, WinForms etc.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference a sequence of labels in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17578631/reference-a-sequence-of-labels-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I did try it with what I knew from other applications. Sorry for being new to this and not immediately jumping to the idea that "Hey, there's probably a system class for this". I could've said PictureBox, TextBox or anything else really. I did forget to mention I'm using WinForms though, I'll give you that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Controls.Find()` method for finding the Label Control by its Control Name.

Try This:

```
for (int i = 0; i < something.length; i++)
{
   ((Label) Controls.Find("lablel"+i,true)[0]).Text = something[i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get an enumerable list of labels from the Controls collection by using [`.OfType<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

e.g.

```
foreach(Label l in this.Controls.OfType<Label>())
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Controls.Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to find all references:

```
for (int i = 0; i < something.length; i++)
{
    var lbl = this.Controls.Find("lable" + i, true);
    if(lbl.Length > 0)
        ((Label)lbl[0]).Text = something[i];
}
```

Another approach using LINQ (which doesn't search recursively as opposed to `Find`):

```
for (int i = 0; i < something.Length; i++)
{
    Label lbl = this.Controls.Cast<Label>()
        .FirstOrDefault(l => l.Name.Equals("lable" + i, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
    if(lbl != null) lbl.Text = something[i];
}
```

However, i would not call this good practise. Your array and the labels are directly related to each other. What hapens if you change the array but forget to change the labels?

You should use a different control like `ListBox` or `DataGridView` or create the labels dynamically according to the size of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Or simply find all the labels without needing to know their names:

```
foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
{
    Label label = ctrl as Label;
    if (label != null)
    {
        label.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, considering I want to assign specific objects specific corresponding (to their name) values, that doesn't help as much.

Comment: You can always check its name. It helps more than you can imagine. Not to mention it is far more readable than the other solutions.